# Secondary groupby aggregation function doesn't compute correctly

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, dask

I'm reading from a parquet file using dask, computing the dataframe, and then, for all intents an purposes, just using pandas.

```
df = dd.read_parquet(path, storage_options={"key": aws_key, "secret": aws_secret})

data = df.compute()

output = data.groupby(["h3", "device_id_value"]).agg(
    dwell_time=("activity_time", lambda x: (x.max() - x.min()).seconds),
    isAndroid=("device_id_type", lambda x: (x == "idfa").unique()),
    isApple=("device_id_type", lambda x: (x == "adid").unique()),
)
```

output gives me something like:

```
h3                 device_id_value                                                     
635258626036566783 xyz-123-123-123-123-123-           0       True    False
635259179052503807 xyz-123-123-123-123-123-           0      False     True
635260102721288383 xyz-123-123-123-123-123-           0       True    False
635326045248161535 xyz-123-123-123-123-123-           0       True    False
635328608959867775 xyz-123-123-123-123-123-           0      False     True
...                                                             ...        ...      ...
635775853111143487 xyz-123-123-123-123-123-           0       True    False
635775855397977471 xyz-123-123-123-123-123-           0      False     True
635775855726568767 xyz-123-123-123-123-123-           0       True    False
635775999273407807 xyz-123-123-123-123-123-           0      False     True
635776004911317951 xyz-123-123-123-123-123-           0      False     True
```

I then want to collapse the data, and only groupby `h3`, via:

```
final = output.groupby("h3").agg(
    android_total=("isAndroid", lambda x: (x == True).sum()),
    apple_total=("isApple", lambda x: (x == True).sum()),
)
```

Strangely, the `apple_total` column works, but the `android_total` column still returns the original `True` or `False` values.

```
                    android_total  apple_total
h3                                            
635258626036566783           True            0
635259179052503807          False            1
635260102721288383           True            0
635326045248161535           True            0
635328608959867775          False            1
...                           ...          ...
635775853111143487           True            0
635775855397977471          False            1
635775855726568767           True            0
635775999273407807          False            1
635776004911317951          False            1
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing or overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

This may be down to the datatypes of the columns (or their data). Check with `.dtypes` that both isAndroid and isApple columns are `bool`. You could also see if there are non-`bool`s in your columns with `.unique()`.

Assuming they are `bool` columns, a more succinct way would be:

```py
final = output.groupby("h3").agg("sum")[["isAndroid","isApple"]]
```